Login page HTTP request sends infinitely
A few hours ago i made a similar question but i was addressing the wrong issues.
the real problem is, i have this functional login function:
async function entrar() {
        const user_name = document.getElementById('user_name').value.trim();
        const password = document.getElementById('password').value.trim();

    try {
        const response = await fetch('/user/search', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
            },
            body: `user_name=${encodeURIComponent(user_name)}&password=${encodeURIComponent(password)}`
        });

        if (!response.ok) {
            throw new Error(`HTTP error! Status: ${response.status}`);
        }

        const objJson = await response.json();

        if (objJson && objJson.user_name === user_name && objJson.password === password) {
            localStorage.setItem('objJson', JSON.stringify(objJson));
            window.location.href = `/index?user_name=${encodeURIComponent(user_name)}&password=${encodeURIComponent(password)}`;
        } else {
            window.location.href = '/login';
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching data:', error);
        window.location.href = '/login'; // Redirect to login page on error
    }
}


it checks on my database if i have some user with the user_name and password specified on the textboxes, and it actually works and responds with the status 200. the problem is, this function redirects me to the route: "/index?user_name=something&password=something" (yes i know it should be encoded, i'll work on that for the future) and this route never responds, it gets stuck on status "pending" just like the image below shows:
this is the route that is not working properly:
app.get('/index', urlencodedParser, async function(req, res){
    let objJson = {};
    if(req.query.user_name) objJson.user_name = req.query.user_name; else objJson.user_name = false;
    if(req.query.password) objJson.password = req.query.password; else objJson.password = false;
    findUserOne(objJson, async function(result){
     if((result)&&(result.activate==true)){
         res.set('Content-Type', 'text/html');        
         const data = await fs.readFileSync('./index.html','utf8');
         await res.send(data);
     }else{
         res.set('Content-Type', 'text/html');
         const data = await fs.readFileSync('./login.html','utf8');
         await res.send(data);
     }
    });
});

my login fields:
<div class="container">
        <h2 align="center">LOGIN</h2>
        <br>
        <center>
            <div align="center" style="width:30%;">
                <input type="text" id="user_name" class="form-control" placeholder="Nome de usuário"><br>
                <input type="password" id="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Senha"><br>
                <br>
                <button class="btn btn-lg btn-info" onclick="entrar()">Entrar</button>
            </div>
        </center>
    </div>



Are you using a <form> tag? Looks like it simply gets submitted.

Actually not, i edited the post with my login fields, i got them from watching a tutorial, i didn't refactor to a form because i wouldn't know much of the logic to do so, but i thought it wouldn't make a difference, do you think that's what causing the issue?

but also my login function has the window.location.href = ``/index?user_name=${user_name}&password=${password};` i imagine it would do the work of a form

Ah yes that line does that. If you don't want it to do that, why do you have that line?

You should know that what you're doing is not real security. It's very easy to circumvent this!

probably stucks here: urlencodedParser, include that code also (and you don't need it, see How to get a URL parameter in Express?. the code is in dire need of refactoring (await has no effect on res.send, why are you sending index.html etc.

i actually want it to redirect the url to the /index route, the problem is, it doesn't returns the index.html page, it gets stuck on the request infinitely

the urlencodedParser is the bodyparser i use, i imported him on const bodyParser = require('body-parser'); and  app.use(urlencodedParser);, i can use this other method to get the url parameter, but so far urlencodedParser was working for me, i removed the await, i tried to include it just to try to see if it could solve

try removing it from the rute, and use it only like app.use(urlencodedParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));, on the route, it's not being initiated properly, most likely causing the pending status, because it gets called, but never returns
